GPS updates (satellites) in background - FusedLocationProvider vs LocationManager, Device Power Saving vs App's Battery Unrestricted, Android version
So depending on which API we use (FusedLocationProvider or LocationManager), battery mode (Device Power Saving or Battery Unrestricted for an app), Android version, the app may not receive GPS updates (from satellites) in the background (when the screen is turned off or app is minimized) using a foreground service (android:foregroundServiceType="location")
Manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" /> -->
<!-- is not needed when we use a foreground service with the location type -->

Starting foreground service mode with the notification:
// Android 14+:
ServiceCompat.startForeground(
    /* service = */ this,
    /* id = */ NOTIFICATION_FOREGROUND_ID,
    /* notification = */notificationBuilder.build(),
    /* foregroundServiceType = */ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION
)

// or Android 13-:
startForeground(
    /* id = */ NOTIFICATION_FOREGROUND_ID,
    /* notification = */ builder.build()
)

Subscribing for GPS updates (by choice, not at the same time):
FusedLocationProvider:
private val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
    /* p0 = */ getLocationRequest(),
    /* p1 = */ this,
    /* p2 = */ looper
)

private fun getLocationRequest(): LocationRequest {
    return LocationRequest.Builder(250L).apply {
        setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(100L)
        setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
    }.build()
}

LocationManager:
private val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    /* provider = */ LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
    /* minTimeMs = */ 250L,
    /* minDistanceM = */ 0L,
    /* listener = */ this,
    /* looper = */ looper
)

So I have tested the following two devices:

Samsung S22 Ultra on Android 14
Xiaomi Poco X3 NFC on Android 12

Identical pre-settings for both devices:

Location is turned ON
Wi-Fi is turned OFF
Cellular network (mobile network) is turned OFF
Bluetooth is turned OFF

So we can receive location updates only from GPS satellites.
Testing cases (at least 1 hour) when starting a foreground service to receive GPS updates from satellites and turning off the screen (lock the device):
1) Device's Power saving is turned OFF, App's Battery is Optimized:


test with FusedLocationProvider:

V Samsung Android 14: updates are received all the time within 1h

V Xiaomi Android 12: updates are received all the time within 1h


test with LocationManager:

V Samsung S22 Ultra on Android 14: updates are received all the time within 1h

X Xiaomi Poco X3 NFC on Android 12: updates are NOT received. But why?! What's the difference from FusedLocationProvider and the different behaviour from Samsung or Android 14?


2) Device's Power saving is turned ON, App's Battery is Optimized:


test with FusedLocationProvider:

X Samsung Android 14: updates are NOT received

V Xiaomi Android 12: updates are received all the time within 1h. So there is no difference whether device's power saving is turned on or off


test with LocationManager:

X Samsung Android 14: updates are NOT received

X Xiaomi Android 12: updates are NOT received. Again, no difference.


3) Device's Power saving is turned ON, App's Battery is Unrestricted:


test with FusedLocationProvider:

X Samsung Android 14: updates are NOT received. Making App's Battery mode unrestricted didn't help to override device's power saving for the app to get GPS updates.

V Xiaomi Android 12: updates are received all the time within 1h. Of course we still get updates because we can get them even with app's optimized battery mode while device's power saving is enabled.


test with LocationManager:

X Samsung Android 14: updates are NOT received. The same, making App's Battery mode unrestricted didn't help to override device's power saving for the app to get GPS updates.

V Xiaomi Android 12: updates are received all the time within 1h. Finally LocationManager has woken up when we made app's battery mode unrestricted, so it doesn't depend on device's power saving and only works when apps's battery mode is unrestricted to get updates in the background.


p.s.: as soon as I unlock any device (the screen is turned on / app visible) the app can get updates for all cases.
Conclusions:

Samsung Android 14:


Both FusedLocationProvider and LocationManager behave the same in all cases.
We can get GPS updates in the background (locked state/screen is turned off) using a foreground service while device's power saving is turned off
Making app's battery mode Unrestricted still doesn't allow to get GPS updates when device's power saving is turned on, so the only way to get the updates is to turn power saving off or unlock the phone (and screen is on)


Xiaomi Android 12:


FusedLocationProvider and LocationManager behave differenly, I have no clue why.
We can get GPS updates in the background using a foreground service in all cases if we use FusedLocationProvider
To get GPS updates with LocationManager in all cases we need to make app's battery mode Unrestricted even when device's power saving is turned off.

It just doesn't make any logic for me, at least with Xiaomi/Android 12. For Samsung/Android 14 I guess the logic is simple - you just can not get GPS updates while device's power saving is on in the background.
p.s.: if someone is still going to suggest ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, please read this.
but all cases were tested with that background permission as well:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

there is no difference between "Allow all the time" and "Allow only while using the app" when we use a foreground service with location type. We need ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION only if we want to get updates in the background without using a foreground service.
So here's the question.
Can someone explain what's going on here? Mb some history of location in the background depending on the Android version or even the phone manufacture, and what about differences between FusedLocationProvider and LocationManager I found with Xiaomi on Android 12?
